# TempData[] не работает после редиректа

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Есть два метода:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Products()
    {
        ViewBag.Message = TempData["message"];
        var data = await _catalogRepository.GetProductsAsync();
        return View(data);
    }
```

и

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> EditProduct(Product product)
    { 
        await _catalogRepository.UpdateProductAsync(product);
        TempData["message"] = "Товар успешно обновлен";
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Products));
    }
```

Почему во втором методе после установки TempData в первом методе оно пустое?

Comment: Почему оно должно быть не пустое? Это же не сессия, чтобы между вызовами контроллеров жить.

Comment: а где первый метод, а где второй?

Comment: сначала срабатывает второй метод, затем первый

Comment: мне нужно чтобы после редиректа модальное окно с сообщением показывалось только один раз, а в случае обновления - не показывалось